# How can I display my content better?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

This is the current format of my content
[image: Screen shot of the app]

The bullets start on the same line with the next paragraph.
Now i want to achieve something like this

[image: What I want to achieve]

I want the paragraph to start at few distance from the bullets. How can i achieve this?

This is my xml

```
<me.biubiubiu.justifytext.library.JustifyTextView
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/practices"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: You can use Webview widgets it can format data as you want and also can use the functionality of html code.

Answer (score 0):

After `bullets` add two space characters in `string`, you can do all at once using
`replaceAll` in `String` as in

```
String bulletCode = "#8226";
String spaceCode = "&#160";
myContent.replaceAll(bulletCode, bulletCode+spaceCode+spaceCode);
```

Comment: let me try and see

Comment: I have tried this. The space characters are added well , however the next lines still start at the same level with the bullet

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved bullet points by this method, you can try this

```
String BULLET_SYMBOL = "&#8226";

    private String text = Html.fromHtml(BULLET_SYMBOL + " +1 new goat every 12 months for 36 months")
                + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                + Html.fromHtml(BULLET_SYMBOL + " 10-30% estimated ROI")
                + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                + System.getProperty("line.separator")
            + Html.fromHtml(BULLET_SYMBOL + " New animal if dead or infertile");

    JustifyTextView practices = (JustifyTextView)findViewById(R.id.practices);
    practices.setText(text);
```

System.getProperty("line.separator") is for new line

Answer (score 0):

For displaying typography with bullets you will need to use appropriate regex in order to indent it as desired.

You may use the following for example :

```
\u2022\s\d\. \s[A-z]
```

This should help you in achieving what is expected.